# SCP from local drive (not C:) to remote server

Tags: scp

Trying to SCP a file on my local E: drive to remote server.  I have tried the following:

```
scp E:\Projects\new_server\ssl.conf user_id@host:/etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

But get:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname e: Name or service not known

How should the local drive be specified other than C:?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to PowerShell and Windows, not Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it is assuming path as hostname, you should try this

change drive

```
e:
```

go to the specified path by cd

```
cd E:\Projects\new_server\ssl.conf
```

use scp to copy the file

```
scp ssl.conf user@host:/etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Comment: Is that using the local command prompt?

Comment: yes, if you are using windows 10 you can use cmd or powershell, to make it more handy just browse to the folder where you have the file hold the shift key and right click from the mouse in the context menu you'll find "open power shell here"

Comment: Looks like that would work with PowerShell.  But I'm getting Permission denied...

Comment: you must be using non-root user, try this to first copy the file in /temp directory then use ssh to mv the file to the conf.d directory, scp ssl.conf user@host:/tmp/

Comment: Ok the first part worked.  Do I do the SSH in terminal or SSH client?  If former how?

Comment: Tried using move in SSH client but get "Renaming remote file '/tmp/ssl.conf' to '/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf' failed. Rename request has failed with SFTP error Failure: Failure."

Comment: ssh the system by using "ssh user@host" then move the file using mv command with sudo privileges "sudo mv /tmp/ssl.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/" for this you must have sudoers rights

Comment: Worked!!  Thanks!